# How to round time to nearest 15 minute in java

Tags: java, time, rounding

My program needs to calculate the overtime periods of workers for salary calculation purposes. To this end, what I am doing now is getting the worker's clock-in  time and out time, then I calculate with the company's time scales and get how many hours overtime each worker has done. I need to round these times to the nearest 15 minutes, so I need a class to pass in the hours and return the rounded hours.

For example:

- if the overtime hours is 2.17 hrs it must be rounded to 2.15.
- if the overtime hours is 2.24 hrs it must be rounded to 2.30.
- if the overtime hours is 2.40 hrs it must be 2.45.
- if the overtime hours is 2.56 hrs it must be 3 hours.

  public String RoundToNearest15Min(long Time) {

  ```
  long milsec = Time;
  System.out.println("milsecond :" + milsec);
  long sec = Time / 1000;
  ValidateValues.roundupDouble(sec);
  System.out.println("second :" + sec);
  double min = sec / 60;
  ValidateValues.roundupDouble(min);
  System.out.println("miniutes :" + min);
  double hrs = min / 60;
  System.out.println("hours :" + hrs);
  double roundeVal = ValidateValues.roundupDouble(hrs);
  String hrsvalue = String.valueOf(roundeVal);
  System.out.println(hrsvalue);

  String splitVal[] = hrsvalue.split("\\.");
  System.out.println(splitVal[0]);
  System.out.println(splitVal[1]);
  int splitedValue2 = Integer.parseInt(splitVal[1]);
  int splitedValue1 = Integer.parseInt(splitVal[0]);

  if (splitedValue2 <= 15) {
      int rounded = splitedValue2 > 7 ? (15) : (0);
      return splitedValue1 + "." + rounded;
  }
  if (splitedValue2 > 15 && splitedValue2 <= 30) {
      int rounded = splitedValue2 > 22 ? (30) : (15);
      return splitedValue1 + "." + rounded;
  }
  if (splitedValue2 > 30 && splitedValue2 <= 45) {
      int rounded = splitedValue2 > 37 ? (45) : (30);
      return splitedValue1 + "." + rounded;
  }
  if (splitedValue2 > 45 && splitedValue2 <= 59) {
      int rounded = splitedValue2 > 51 ? (00) : (45);
      if (rounded == 00) {
          splitedValue1++;
          return splitedValue1 + "." + rounded;
      } else {
          return splitedValue1 + "." + rounded;
      }
  }
  return "";
  ```

  }

Comment: i have use some calculations but didn't workout them.

Comment: What is the "time instance" used here, `long epoch`, `Date`, `LocalDate`, `Calendar`, ... rounding is usually done with a modulo operator. Show what you have, to help you on that part

Comment: this is the class now im using ,

Comment: oh man code is too long to show, any way now im doing is pass the long value to a method and divided that long value until i get the hour value, and the do some if else logic to round

Comment: here is link to my code which im using now
http://d-h.st/hSpv

Comment: I won't click that link, edit your question with the interesting part of your code. No need of the full project, only the method where you are trying to round the time to quarter.

Comment: Tidy up, format and correct English.

Answer (score 4):

If you just can get minutes extracted from the time and pass it to this function:

```
public static int getNear15Minute(int minutes){
        int mod = minutes%15; 
        int res = 0 ;
        if((mod) >=8){
            res = minutes+(15 - mod);
        }else{
            res = minutes-mod;
        }
        return res; //return rounded minutes
    }
```

here I assumed number greater than or equal to 8 is near to 15.

Answer (score 1):

Well, rounding is easy to do with a modulo operation.

Here you want to round to a 15minutes.

Using the epoch time in milliseconds, you just need to remove the remainder of the modulo operation like this :

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
l -= l % (15*60*1000);


System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println(new Date(l));
```

> Tue Jan 03 09:35:56 CET 2017
>
> Tue Jan 03 09:30:00 CET 2017

`15*60*1000` is simply the number of milliseconds in 15minutes

You just need to check the value of the remainder to add 15minute if need.
So just store the remainder :

```
long r = l % (15*60*1000);
```

Then substract it to the current time

```
l -= r;
```

And check the number of minute (depends on the precision you really wants.

```
if( r / 60_000 >= 8)
     l += 15*60*1000;
```

This will round up if the quarter is past from 8minutes (if this really means anything in english ;) )

Full code :

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
long r = l % (15*60*1000);
l -= r;
if( r / 60_000 >= 8)
     l += 15*60*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Example that uses current `Date`

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int round = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 15;
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, round < 8 ? -round : (15-round));
        calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

Test

```
Tue Jan 03 09:15:00 CET 2017
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/Wctjpe)

Comment: That's using `Calendar` not `Date`, with `Date`, you should do a `timeInMilli - (timeInMilli % (15*60*1000))` I think. PS : `Calendar.getInstance()` is already doing a `new Date()` so no need to do it again ;)