# Get the specific 15 minutes timeframe based on current time

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I would like to get the 15 minutes timeframe based on Current Time.

**For example:**

Timeframe is for `every 15 minutes`.

i.e 12 to 1 is divided into four timeframes `[ 12:00 to 12:15, 12:16 to 12:30, 1:31 to 12:45, 12:46 to 1:00]`

If the current time is `12:34` means, i need to return the timeframe as `12:31 to 12:45`

Is it something we can do easily with Java 8 Date and Time API?

Comment: That funny, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41438768/4391450) is recent and quite close. Homework ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a `TemporalAdjuster` that calculates the end of the current 15-minute period and calculate the start of the period by removing 14 minutes.

Could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  LocalTime t = LocalTime.of(12, 34);
  LocalTime next15 = t.with(next15Minute());
  System.out.println(next15.minusMinutes(14) + " - " + next15);
}

public static TemporalAdjuster next15Minute() {
  return (temporal) -> {
    int minute = temporal.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
    int next15 = (minute / 15 + 1) * 15;
    return temporal.with(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0).plus(next15, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
  };
}
```

which outputs `12:31 - 12-45`.

Note: I'm not sure how it behaves around DST changes - to be tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Or just `int minutesDiff = 15 - minute%15;`…

Comment: @Holger actually neither as it would retain the seconds/nanos. Edited to reset to midnight first.

Comment: Ok, but when you care for nanos, it makes more sense to calculate with them in the first place, which again allows for using modulo instead of divide, round and multiply: `temporal.plus(900000000000L - temporal.getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY)%900000000000L, ChronoUnit.NANOS)`. Production code would use a `static final` field for the constant, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the Date API and calculate the intervals.
Divide with your interval (15 min) and multiply again. This will strip off the minutes and round to the lower 15 minutes interval. Now you have to add fifteen minutes to get your needed output. See the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long ms = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("Current time: " + new Date().toString());

        long fifteen = 15 * 60 * 1000;
        long newMs = (ms / fifteen) * fifteen + fifteen;
        System.out.println("Calculated time: " + new Date(newMs));
    }
}
```

See [running example](http://ideone.com/UtjOQu)

EDIT:

[Running example](http://ideone.com/3PHihH) with LocalDate

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        System.out.println(now);

        LocalTime next = now.with((temp) -> {
            int currentMinute = temp.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
            int interval = (currentMinute / 15) * 15 + 15;
            temp = temp.with(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0);
            temp = temp.with(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0);
            return temp.with(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY, interval);  
        });
        System.out.println(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: The asker asked about the Java 8 Date and Time API. I too think that it’s preferrable to use this rather than `java.util.Date` and long arithmetic.

Comment: @OleV.V., I agree to use LocalDate but arithmetic is still easier. (Note that this could be clearer)

Comment: @AxelH, thank you for your always knowledgeable input. I find it more convenient and easier to read to do the arithmetic in minutes than in milliseconds (you need not agree, of course). Certainly some arithmetic is needed.

Comment: @OleV.V. indeed, I can understand that this is more readable for some people to get the value in minutes instead of `60 * 1000 ms`. Even if this is some usual values.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your feedback. I added an example with LocalDate and calculation with minutes. Mainly i prefer the calculation with milliseconds but i think this is a matter of taste. But in some cases unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler approach with LocalTime

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int interval = 15; //Can be customized to any value
  LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
  int minuteOfDay = now.toSecondOfDay() / 60;
  int mod = (minuteOfDay / interval + 1) * interval;
  System.out.println("lower bound" + LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay((mod - interval) * 60));
  System.out.println("Upper bound" + LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(mod * 60));
}
```